# image attachment from camera or photo library MFmessage/MailcomposeViewController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Am wondering if i can attach an image to my SMSComposerSheet (like the message application in the iPhone does). I've already implemented image picking (from library and camera)
So may be i need some thing to add in the displaySMSComposerSheet method to allow That.

One other thing, i want to do the same thing with mails sending, but i think that i couldn't, so i was thinking about saving the image into the application's sandbox then attach it to the mail. but i don't know how to do that :s

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To try use this https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/how-to-attach-an-image-from-your-photo-gallery-and-send-it-as-an-image-on-iphone/